# smoothScrollToPosition in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, scroll, expandablelistview, android-animation

I'm trying to scroll to the bottom of an `ExpandableListView` with the [`smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) method but fail because i have no idea how to calculate the *position* attribute.

Neither

```
adapter.getGroupCount()
```

nor

```
adapter.getChildrenCount(getGroupCount()-1);
```

nor

```
public int getLastIndex() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int g = 0; g < getGroupCount(); g++)
        count += getChildrenCount(g) + 1;
    return count;
}
```

did the trick.

TLDR: How can I (smooth-)scroll to the bottom of a `ExpandableListView` on API level 8+?

Comment: In what context do you try to call this method, I mean in what event do you want to implement this functional?

Answer (score 0):

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        parent.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This should scroll to the clicked item, not to the last position. no?

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(listView.getCount()*2, 0, 5000);
    }
});
```

`ExpandableListView.post()` to wait for the list to finish loading the items.
`ExpandableListView.getCount()` to get the count of the items (groups and children)

Provide a duration so the list doesn't scroll to quickly (method requires API 11)
`smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(int position, int offset, int duration)`

Answer (score 0):

You are calculated the position:

```
public int getLastIndex() {
    int count = 0;
    for (int g = 0; g < getGroupCount(); g++)
        count += getChildrenCount(g) + 1;
    return count;
}
```

You can use it to scroll

```
expandableListView.smoothScrollToPosition(getLastIndex());
```

But, If you call `smoothScrollToPosition()` method in `onCreate()` method of Activity class, you should call  `smoothScrollToPosition()` method after UI is shown on screen by using Handler:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .....
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            expandableListView.smoothScrollToPosition(getLastIndex());
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but `smoothScrollToPosition` is not called during the initialization phase.

Answer (score 0):

The position to use depends on whether each group is expanded or not.  If the group is expanded, add all of its children to the position count. Otherwise, don't!

```
int getPosition(ExpandableListView listView, ExpandableListViewAdapter adapter) {
    int position = 0;
    for (int group = 0; group < adapter.getGroupCount(); ++group) {
        position += 1;
        if (listView.isGroupExpanded(group)) {
            position += adapter.getChildrenCount(group);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this position should bring you to the bottom of the list view.